# How to disable click pointer-events in parts of iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Actually I want to disable pointer events in some part of the iframe. So my idea is to place a div over the iframe in the top and then disable pointer events of that div.

Here is my Code..

```
<html>

<body>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="bar"> </div>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_VNad" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>  </iframe>
  </div>
  <style>
    .holder {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .frame {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .bar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: green;
      pointer-events: none;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

But it did not disable the pointer-event on the iframe.Please please Suggest how I can achieve this???
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have your `pointer-events` usage backward. If you set `pointer-events: none` on an element, the browser will pass the event to the next element behind it.

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of pointer events, the value none instructs the pointer event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.
> — [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Instead you should simply leave the `pointer-events` property off and your “spaceball” element will be the target of the click event, preventing it from reaching the iframe.